# CodeIgniter Update Not Working

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update

I have a form in a modal that I'm using to do an update on a record. The form seems to submit okay, the URL in the browser points to the right location (domain.net/cities/update_city/1) but no view shows up and the record is never updated. I've searched the internet but most tutorials seem to skim over the update or hardcode the id to update. I've only been using CI for a week.

Model Code

```
// Edit City
function edit_city($city_id) {
    $data = array('city_name' => $this->input->post('city_name'));
    $this->db->where('city_id', $city_id);
    $this->db->update('cities', $data);
}
```

View Code (Form is in a modal and gets city_id added by jQuery)

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('/cities/update_city/'); ?>
        <label class="control-label" for="name">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" value=""/><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-small btn-primary" value="Edit City" />
        <button class="btn-small" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<script>
  // scripts for modal windows
      $(document).on("click", ".edit-modal", function () {
      var city_name = $(this).data('name');
      var city_id = $(this).data('id');
      $(".modal-body #city_name").val( city_name );
      //set the forms action to include the city_id
      $(".modal-body form").attr('action','/cities/update_city/'+city_id);
      $('#editCityDialog').modal('show');
  });
```

Controller Code

```
// Update City
function update_city($city_id) {
$this->load->model('cities_model');

    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $data = array('city_name' => $this->input->post('city_name'));

        $this->cities_model->edit_city('cities', array('city_id' => $city_id),$data);
        redirect('/cities');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, you can use it to update easily (i'm bad at english, sorry).

Model:

```
class Cities_model extends CI_Model{
    function edit($table,$where,$data){
       foreach ($where as $key => $value){
            $this->db->where($key,$value);
        }
        $this->db->update($table,$data);        
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    function update_city($city_id){
    $this->load->model('cities_model');
         if($this->input->post('submit'){
         $data = array('city_name' => $this->input->post('city_name'));

         $this->cities_model->edit('cities',array('city_id' => $city_id),$data); //(table,where,data); see in model.
         redirect(''); 
         }
     }
```

*** if you go a link as "http://......update_city/2" and a function update_city($city_id), $city_id will receive as "2" and you need not to write uri_segment to get $city_id. Hope that help you

EDIT :

Controller:

```
function update_city($city_id) {
$this->load->model('cities_model');

if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
    $this->cities_model->edit_city($city_id);
    redirect('/cities');
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I've updated the code above to match your controller code. I don't understand your model code with the $table $where and $data. I won't be passing these to the model since the table and where are always the same for this function. The cities view is showing up now when the form is submitted so I'm getting closer, though the record does not update yet.

Comment: i have edited your controller code, see at bottom of my post. try it.
i want to tell you many things else but i can't. i'm very very bad at english!!!

Comment: That worked, thank you. I'll have to print these out and spend some time walking through the code so I can understand exactly what's going on.